# How to renew Localhost certificate to run localhost in MacOS?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, ssl, ssl-certificate

I'm using a React app with `HTTPS=true npm start` command and until today the App was perfectly running on the localhost. Today I received the following message from Chrome and have no idea how to run the App again. To use my backend APIs, I need to run the app with HTTPS. When I check my certificates, It says that **the localhost certificate was expired yesterday.**

I tried to Add the current certificate to the system Keychain, tried to generate a key.pem and re-run the localhost. None of those worked for me. How can I run my app again?

[image]